# Parse error: java.io.File to com.google.api.services.drive.model.File

Tags: java, android, parsing, file-upload, google-drive-api

**Error:**

> incompatible types: java.io.File cannot be converted to com.google.api.services.drive.model.File

I have this error when i want to use the code to upload a file to drive. I am using the drive API in android studio.

```java
File fileMetadata = new File("video.mp4");
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(mVideoFileName);
fileMetadata.createNewFile();
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("video/mp4", filePath);
Drive driveService = getDriveService(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
        .setFields("1DpOLhFd4_ZpeQTvROBAmIyfarn80Yg5S")
        .execute();
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: It seems like you used a file of type `java.io.File` where a type of file `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File` was expected. Could you provide more of the code, the line numbers and the line numbers mentioned in the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

java.io.File is a file in the local file system,
while com.google.api.services.drive.model.File is a Google Drive file.

You need to use the com.google.api.services.drive.model.File object to represent the Google Drive file you want to create and upload, instead of the java.io.File object.

Change the code to:

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
fileMetadata.setName("video.mp4");
```

This should resolve the incompatibility issue.